# Windows 10 UWP app development) Media casting to multiple devices by DLNA

Tags: windows, casting, uwp, streaming, dlna

I am developing a UWP app for media (audio) casting. I has two remote speakers and can be connected by the DLNA standard.

I hope to my app broadcast audio streaming to remote speakers by DLNA. To do this, i tried to use below.

`Windows.Media.Casting`

- `CastingConnection`
- `CastingDevice`

`Windows.Media.Playback`

- `MediaPlayer`

Because the app have to be broadcaster for speakers, make connection to speaker using `CastingConnection` class and request media source start by this method `RequestStartCastingAsync(CastingSource)`.

The first connection is success and play music correctly. But when a second connection is success, the first connection is disconnected.

The DLNA can only cast to one device and can not streaming to multiple device?

Or are there any other way to media streaming to multiple device?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? Then, I could test on my side.